# bootstrap grid layout from left to right column

Tags: ruby, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

i have been experimenting with rails 6 and I'm stuck regarding a certain bootstrap grid placement. i want to create something in the lines of a photo blog. meaning people can upload photos or text and it should get displayed in a grid system filling 4 columns and then moving down from left to right till eventually reach like 5 rows and then code in pagination (but that's for another time) .
So far ive made a grid and can display anything uploaded to the databse but my code fills only the first row and not moving from left to right. any suggestions?

```
<tbody>
    <% @ads.each do |ad| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= ad.title %></td>
        <td><%= ad.description %></td>
        <td><%= ad.area %></td>
        <td><%= ad.contact %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Ad', new_ad_path %>


<div class="container">
  <% @ads.each do |ad| %>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"> <%= ad.title %> </h5>
        <p class="card-text"><%= ad.description %></p>
        <p class="card-text"><%= ad.area %></p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link"><%= ad.contact %></a>
        </div>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I am assuming what you mean by "moving down from left to right" you mean starting a new row from the left after the first row has been filled by 4 items(photos or text).

I don't think you want to use the Bootstrap grid system for this. CSS Grid was made for this.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ 

You should also change the title of your question. This has nothing to do with Rails 6.

Comment: I mean having a first row moving like 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 and then going down one row and continuing. I thought maybe ruby had a way to do that since each.do puts them one down from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) in the following way.

This example is pure ruby, but you can easily transpose to rails view with proper erb and html markups:

```
ads = (11..24) # emulates your collection

items_per_row = 5
ads.each_slice(items_per_row) do |row_items|
  # start a row: <div class="row mt-3">
  row_items.each do |item|
    # start a columnn: <div class="col-sm">
      print "| #{item}" # only for this demo, add your item with markup here
    # close the column: </ div>
  end
  # close the row: </ div>
  puts # only for this demo, remove in erb
end
```

The above code as pure Ruby returns:

```
# | 11| 12| 13| 14| 15
# | 16| 17| 18| 19| 20
# | 21| 22| 23| 24
```